# Flash Ad to HTML5 using Swiffy - ClickTags not working

Tags: google-swiffy

We’re working on some banners for a client that uses DoubleClick Campaign Manager via their Media Agency.
To date we have produced Flash, but we’ve been asked to produce HTML5 from now on.

So, short term, we’d like to use Swiffy to convert the Flash to HTML5 as we’re amending a set of previous ads, but we not sure how to pass through the correct click tag.

We usually use:

```
on(release){

getURL(_root.clickTag,"_blank");

}
```

Which we have implemented in the Flash, but the click tag isn’t being read correctly when the media agency upload to DCM. The rest of the banner appears as expected.

**Do we need to add additional code to the HTML to pass through the ClickTag correctly?**

We have a super short timeline, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DoubleClick does not support Swiffy files. The best thing to do is use DoubleClick's built-in HTML5 converter and then add **displayHTML5=true** as an additional key-value so that HTML5 is served up by default and Flash is used as a fallback. This way you can just code the clickTag in Flash like you normally would.

Comment: Now that sounds like a much simpler idea. Let me check if the media agency can make that happen...

Comment: Just to follow up on this: we did as you suggested and everything was OK. So nothing new needed as DoubleClick can do everything at their end. Cheers for the tip.

Comment: Good to hear, happy to help!

Comment: Just found out - apparenty this didn't work and the agency used the backup GIFs instead

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to upload Swiffy files into DFP Premium that were provided from 3rd parties. You can track clicks and add your own destination URL by adding

```
stage.setFlashVars("clickTag=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%");
```

Just change out clickTag for whatever the variable was set to within the SWF.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this script in the head tag:

```
<meta name=”ad.size” content=”width=300,height=250”>
<script type="text/javascript">var clickTag = "http://www.google.com"; </script>
```

and the click-throug URL :

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
   <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 300px; height: 250px"></div>
</a>
```

for more Doubleclick info:
https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/3145300?hl=it

Answer (score 0):

put this line of code : stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%http://websiteURL.com"); 
right above the stage.start();
your problem should be solved doing this.